# Different class method signatures based on instantiator?

Tags: typescript

I have a class with methods and depending on where the class is instantiated, I want the methods to have a different signature.

It's for a EventEmitter abstraction, and so having the full class for every possible event would increase the codebase by a lot. I've tried some things with generics, but since I'm new to TypeScript, unfortunately to no avail.

```js
class EventEmitter {
  private eventName: string;

  constructor(eventName: string) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
  }

  public addListener = (listener: any) => {
    // add eventName listener
  }

  public removeListener = (listener: any) => {
    // remove eventName listener
  }

  public hasListener = (listener: any) => {
    // has eventName listener?
  }
}

const event = new EventEmitter('eventName');
```

Different `event`s have a different `listener` signatures, and defining a full class for each of them seems like the wrong approach to me, but maybe that's how it's done in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the type of the event listener based on the event, you can have an type parameter to represent type signature of the function:

```
class EventEmitter<T extends (...a:any[])=> void> {
  private eventName: string;

  constructor(eventName: string) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
  }

  public addListener = (listener: T) => {
    // add eventName listener
  }

  public removeListener = (listener: T) => {
    // remove eventName listener
  }

  public hasListener = (listener: T) => {
    // has eventName listener?
  }
}

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter<(a: string) => void>('eventName');
```

Comment: Fast, working answer. Thanks a lot. I've tried without the `extends`, and that works too. I guess I have to read up on generics - but if you don't mind explaining why you added the `extends`, that'd be interesting.